# window.history.back() for jquery ".load" content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to load content dynamically:

```
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".container").load("https://website.com/page/ .my_class 
  });
});
```

If I now press the "back" button in the bowser the call will not work of course - but how can I fix this for `.load()` content?

Comment: Use [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), although you will need to manually handle the `popstate` state event to undo all the UI changes this `load()` call made. As such, this is not a trivial request.

Comment: OK ;( - I was hoping there is an universal way. But thx for the pushState() tip!

Comment: Unfortunately not. Hope it helps